# Summarizing a repetitive code in a void loop function

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

How can I summarize dozens of code lines for blinking a red LED in Arduino Rich Shield? Is there a way or method to eliminate at least half of the code for repetitive scenarios?

```
const int redPin = 4;


void setup()
{
 pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(redPin, HIGH);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(redPin, HIGH);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(redPin, HIGH);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(redPin, HIGH);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
  delay(250);
}
```

I'm not quite sure what you're after but this is shorter and would get you equivalent results.  Since loop is going to repeat anyway, there's no need to repeat yourself inside loop.

Per the comments, not that this is particularly useful...

```
const int redPin = 4;

int counter = 0;

void setup()
{
 pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if(counter < 4) {
     digitalWrite(redPin, HIGH);
     delay(250);
     digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
     delay(250);
     counter++;
  }      
}
```

Comment: ok I didn't know that, but what if I wanted 3 to 5 blinks and then stop red LED? would that result change in code?

Comment: If you want to stop it (and don't do anything else), move the code to `setup` which is only executed once.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I want it in a loop function, to stop it from blinking after 3 to 5 blinks for instance

Comment: The point of loop is that it keeps repeating.  If you want it to stop after so many blinks then you need to have a variable that starts out at zero and adds one every time the loop runs.  Put the part that blinks the light inside an if statement that checks to see if that number is below whatever limit.

Comment: Aha now I understand the logic behind stopping a certain loop, thank you so much Delta, that was of a great help from you!